# how to use $* but it doesnt consider a special arguement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to use $* in a loop but the first argument is ignored.

in other words:

```bash
    sum=0
    for i in $*
    do
        if [ $1 = "+" ]; then
        sum=$(($sum+$i))
        fi
    done
    echo $sum
```

Comment: You did not say, how you actually call the script, what is the expected output, and what is the output you actually see. The first argument is not ignored: Iti is even used twice (Once it is stored on `i` during the first iteration of the loop, and then it is permanently present in `$1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the first parameter, use `shift`.

But before you shift, you should store the value somewhere.

As the first parameter doesn't change, you can check it just once before starting the loop:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
op=$1
shift

if [ "$op" = + ] ; then
    sum=0
    for i in $* ; do
        sum=$(($sum+$i))
    done
    echo $sum
fi
```

Note that you don't need the quotes around `+`. You *should* quote the `$op` in the condition, though, to prevent parsing errors (try running the script specifying an empty string `""` as the first argument).

When using `$((`, note that you can use shorter and faster way to increment a variable:

```
((sum+=i))
```

Comment: Note, too, that if `$op` isn't going to change, you can simply check it *once* to determine if the loop should be executed at all, rather than repeatedly checking it to determine if `sum` should be updated.